# How can I close Cortana's Confirmation Screen after issuing a voice command?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-10, win-universal-app, cortana

I think I've successfully figured out how to utilize cortana, send commands, and work asynchronously between an app and a service.

But I can't figure out if it's possible to manually close Cortana's Confirmation Screen. I do my voice command, send my ReportSuccessAsync, but the Confirmation Screen stays open.

I wanted to utilize voice commands to **not obsctruct** what the user was currently doing. So if the cortana window had to be open, I wanted to show it only as minimal as possible.

Is there a command that may be sent to manually close the screen and return to normal app state?

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting. The answer may already be posted here, but I found that after the Cortana window pops up (and stays onscreen), that saying, "Hey Cortana, close Cortana" makes the window go away. Simple, and annoying that the window stays up, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is sort of "my app has voice commands," but the Cortana paradigm is more designed around "I am using Cortana to interact with an app." There's not really a need to close that window if the interactions are working through Cortana. That said, if you use deep linking to launch as a foreground app, Cortana should terminate. It will still pass the information to your app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt445538.aspx

Answer (score 0):

## ***Voice Command to close Cortana's Active or Static Window***

Try this. Say "Hey Cortana", wait for listening response. Then say "Please Close". This Usually works for me. It seems that the word "Please" at the beginning of a Cortana communication or preceding a command tends to give the following text a more centralized, isolated, or dare say personalized context, generating an altered response to the following given command. The P word doesn't seem to have a very broad effect on Cortana's Cognitive Library that I have noticed just yet, but I haven't focused much effort on researching responses across the English Literary Spectrum. But I encourage you to *please* throw at her *anything* you feel like and if possible, shoot back the pertinent info here so that we all can learn from, benefit from, and possibly discover new tools to make this thing work more cooperatively, to share with us so that **we all can benefit and prosper** from making our electronics equipment work more for us and not us working hard at making them function properly. Besides, I myself still wants to know how to make her lean toward performing a real action rather than simply defaulting by pulling up a webpage In response to a Stated Command. ~~ P.S. Since the last Quality Update, she has occasionally pulled up the browser search after this command sequence. It would seem that MS believes that all of our commands, inquiries, and statements belong in a Bing Box, and that the proper response *lies* in the resulting pages. So, GOOD LUCK !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if you say "Cancel" it works!

You can use it to:

1. Cancel your search while you are speaking.
2. Close whatever window that Cortana opens like alarms or metric conversions, does
   not work with bing explorer. Sometimes you need to say again "Hey
   Cortana" before "Cancel" to get the windows close.